# How to early exit a composition of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'd like to do something like this:

```
return1stPromise()
  .then(if1stPromiseSucceeds) // returns 2nd Promise
  .catch(if1stPromiseFails)
  .then(if2ndPromiseSucceeds) // execute only if 1st Promise succeeds
```

I'd like the 2nd `.then` to execute only if 1st Promise succeeds. Or in different words - I don't want the 2nd `.then` to execute if the catch has been executed.

Is this even possible or do I have nest the 2nd promise inside the first `then` like this:

```
return1stPromise()
  .then(function (data) {
    return if1stPromiseSucceeds(data).then(if2ndPromiseSucceeds);
  })
  .catch(if1stPromiseFails);
```

In addition - any good resources on how to control flow with Promises where it's more thread like?

Comment: Your `catch` will be called if any of the promises in the chain fail, not only the first. Can you be more specific about what you'd like to happen?

Comment: "Is this even possible". Yes it is. What you have posted will work that way.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough: I'd like the 2nd `.then` to execute only if 1st Promise succeeds. Or in different words - I don't want the 2nd `.then` to execute if the `catch` has been executed. Updated question.

Comment: @krulik: Well, that changes the question significantly.

Comment: I believe what you actually want is `return1stPromise().then(x => if1stPromiseSucceeds(x).then(if2ndPromiseSucceeds), if1stPromiseFails)`. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) about the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is typically the case when we want to react to an exception but not actually handle it and let the code keep running:

```
return1stPromise()
  .then(if1stPromiseSucceeds) // returns 2nd Promise
  .catch(() => { if1stPromiseFails(); throw e; })
  .then(if2ndPromiseSucceeds) // execute only if 1st Promise succeeds
```

You need to *rethrow* the exception in order to mark it as "still not handled".

This is like synchronous code:

```
try {
  var res = firstResult();
  var res2 = ifFirstPromiseSucceeds(res);
} catch (e) {
    ifFirstPromiseFails();
    throw e; // we reacted to the exception but did not handle it yet.
}
var res3 = ifSecondPromiseSucceeds();
```

I think thinking of promises in terms of threads is mostly confusing - finding a *synchronous* analogy is always easier if possible.

It's not always possible, for example another way to stop a promise chain in the way is *cancellation* which is a little like a thread abort with "I don't care about the results" semantics - you can [read about it here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancelable-promises) but I think for your use case it's a little over the top and not as nice.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Only problem is that in my specific case I'd rather not throw another error (which doesn't make sense to catch).

Comment: In the meantime went for the nesting alternative (updated answer with nested code).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do throws and catches but if you don't want to do, you can always return a rejected promise to bypass the next then stage. Such as;

```js
new Promise((resolve,reject) => { var rnd = Math.random();
                               rnd > 0.5 ? resolve(21)
                                         : reject("promise error");
                                })
    .then(val  => { var rnd = Math.random();
                    if (rnd < 0.5) return Promise.reject("then error");
                    return Promise.resolve(val*2);
                  })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err);
                    return Promise.reject("you won't see this");
                  })
    .then(val  => console.log("Both the promise and the first then stage worked fine and resulted: ", val));
```

The last `then` stage callback will only be invoked if the first promise and the second promise at the first `then` stage resolves.